# Calling non-inline functions from inline functions

Tags: c++, inline

In a library, I have the following in a header:

```
// button.hpp

class ExtraButtons
{
public:
    static inline void show() { setShown(true); }
    static inline void hide() { setShown(false); }
    static void setShown(bool shown);
};
```

and the following in a source file:

```
#include "button.hpp"

void ExtraButtons::setShown(bool shown)
{
}
```

The library compiles fine. However, when I'm using the library and I include `button.hpp`, I get this error from the `setShown` calls in `show()` and `hide()`:

```
undefined reference to `ExtraButtons::setShown(bool)'
```

I can fix the problem by removing the inline from `show()` and `hide()` and defining them in the source file, like normal, OR by making `setShown` inline as well. Why is this the case? Are these the only solutions?

Comment: If you want this to link, you'll need to provide *both* object files to the linker.  How are you invoking the linker?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that `inline` would have such a big effect. In my experience, `inline` is more a reminder to yourself that you expect the function to be compiled inline, rather than something else.

Comment: @MrLister: The purpose of `inline` is to allow definitions in multiple translation units (which is often necessary for the compiler to be able to inline it). But you're right that that shouldn't make a difference here.

Comment: That `bool const &` in the error message is a bit suspicious, when the type is just `bool` in the code. Are you sure you've shown us the exact code you're compiling? Have you changed the header and not recompiled some files that include it?

Comment: @MikeSeymour Sorry, the `bool const &` was a mistake on my part. I had just changed that in the code.

Comment: Afaik, the compiler is already allowed to inline the functions when they are defined in the class definition like this...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like either you aren't linking the library binary into your project, or your *actual* definition for `setShown` is `inline void ExtraButtons::setShown(bool shown)` (note that it's accidentally marked inline in the source file).